# .htaccess modrewrite not redirecting my links

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm changing my website links to a SEO friendly urls, I did every thing in php file and changed the urls as following:

http://mywebsiet.com/news-details.php?id=2012/6/21/newstitle.html

how can I redirect to:

http://mywebsiet.com/2012/6/21/newstitle.html

I tried this Generating tool from www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

and created the .htaccess with the code provided:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)$ /news-details.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and even so, nothing get changed.... any ideas?

Comment: Just checking -- What are you expecting to change? (Since you have constructed an internal rewrite, the URL in your browser will not change.)

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html)$ /news-details.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava, I tried it bot also not working, I'm on shared hosting and I asked the support, they told me that the mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: Make sure above .htaccess is in DOCUMENT_ROOT and you have `news-details.php` at the same level. I will edit the answer a bit, try it.

Comment: yes it is, the file news-details.php and .htaccess are in the same directory (public_html), thank you again

Comment: Ok good, did the edit code work for you? (I will check tomorrow, way past bed time for me)

Comment: is there any options that I need to change in the php.ini file?

Comment: Nothing to do with php.ini actually. What is the URL that you tested and didn't work for you?

Comment: since nothing worked I changed the links to defults:

here is a link:

http://in-goal.com/news-details.php?id=226

thank you in advance